# Mutant City Blues Example Characters

Tags: gumshoe, mutant-city-blues

I am running Mutant City Blues for the first time, and have never played or run a Gumshoe based game before. I am providing pre-generated characters for the players, and have come up with attributes for them. However, I have nothing to compare them to in order to judge whether what I have produced is reasonable and balanced.

I have searched for sources of existing example player characters but have been unable to find anything. I am aware that there are existing examples for other Gumshoe settings, but character creation rules vary from setting to setting, and I want something specific to Mutant City Blues. I also know and have followed the very general, brief guidelines in the rulebook.

**Are there any existing resources for example/pre-generated characters for Mutant City Blues?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do hope that it is still relevant, or maybe it will just [hopefully] help you in the future, but I've just found this sample online campaign which took place a few years ago. As it seems, it does have a few character sheets within it, so without much further ado here it is:

http://codeindigo.livejournal.com/2008/07/05/

There are 2 of the 3 character sheets in this page, and I'm quite sure that I found the third one not that long after.

Hope it helps.